# Prefilling gmail compose screen with <a> tags in body From URL

Tags: javascript, url, gmail, url-encoding

This code works to add text with new lines.

```
 https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&ui=2&tf=0&fs=1&to=WHOEVER%40COMPANY.COM&su=SUBJECTHERE&body=LINE1%0aLINE2
```

My problem is that when i enter A tags to body of email, The HTML displays in body.

Eg:

```
<a href="link.php">Link</a>
```

I will see the full HTML in body of email.

How could i send body with HTML Links inside that will display correct as text in body of message in gmail?

Thanks.